# How to access json variable to another json using jquery?

Tags: jquery, json

I want to access first json variable to second json url

```
    var responce_code; 
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
       responce_code = (data.etsy_response_code);
    }  

    $.getJSON("<?=base_url()?>etsy/getListing/responce_code", function(data) {  
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var responce_code; 
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    responce_code = (data.etsy_response_code);
    $.getJSON("<?=base_url()?>etsy/getListing/" + responce_code, function(data){ 
   }); 
});
```

Comment: sir using seprate function not within function

Comment: that does not matter, You still need to nest the calls or make sure one is not called before the other finished

Answer (score 1):

There are two things need to be changed:

1. You have to write the variable outside of the string. Otherwise it is just part of the string.
2. Because `getJSON` is asyncronous you have to nest the second one inside the first. Otherwise the second request may be started before the first one is finished and so your `responce_code` is still emtpy.

Like this:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    var responce_code = (data.etsy_response_code);
    $.getJSON("<?=base_url()?>etsy/getListing/" + responce_code, function() {
        // second callback
    });  
});
```

Comment: I want in selerate json function not within function

Comment: You have to work within callbacks, otherwise you can't handle it. The first request has to be executed, before the second one can start, otherwise the variable `responce_code` has no content and the second request will fail.

Answer (score -1):

You have to do a second `$.getJSON` from within the `callback` function of first call. Its an `ajax` GET call. So do it like below:

```
var responce_code; 
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
   //success callback
   responce_code = (data.etsy_response_code);

   $.getJSON("<?=base_url()?>etsy/getListing/responce_code", function(data) {  
        //2nd call success callback
   });  
});
```

Answer (score -1):

May be this is what u need

Use AJAX instead

```
var response= $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        url:"Your Url"
})
var data = JSON.parse(response.ResponseText)


$.getJSON("<?=base_url()?>etsy/getListing/"+data.responce_code , function(data) {  
    }
```

Mark as answer if it helps

Comment: Instead of down voting someone can add why the answer was wrong. so that a user can learn from their failures.